# How can I load a model in PyTorch without redefining the model?

Tags: model, save, load, pytorch

I am looking for a way to save a pytorch model, and load it without the model definition. By this I mean that I want to save my model including model definition.

For example, I would like to have two scripts. The first would define, train, and save the model. The second would load and predict the model without including the model definition.

The method using `torch.save(), torch.load()` requires me to include the model definition in the prediction script, but I want to find a way to load a model without redefining it in the script.

Comment: AFAIK An artifact of the dynamic nature of the computation graph in pytorch makes a general solution functionally impossible. It is possible to save an instance of the current computation graph but if your model has forks then the resulting graph may not completely represent your model.

Comment: Note that these issues are resolved if you implement your model as a TorchScript module. If you can successfully export to TorchScript then this will also be a solution. I'll try to add an answer later detailing this comment. For now take a look [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-should-i-use-tracing-rather-than-scripting/53883).

Comment: @김수호, Could you clarify what you mean by "using `torch.save(), torch.load()` requires ... the model definition in the prediction script"?  My experience and my [reading of the documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html#saving-and-loading-models-with-shapes) is that `torch.save(model, 'model.pt')` and `model = torch.load('model.pt')` already allow saving the model definition (which is pickled together with the parameters; of course, doing so is more brittle to changes in the dependencies of the model that was pickled).

Answer (score 14):

You can attempt to export your model to [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#builtin-functions) using [tracing](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/jit.html#torch.jit.trace). This has limitations. Due to the way PyTorch constructs the model's computation graph on the fly, if you have any control-flow in your model then the exported model may not completely represent your python module. TorchScript is only supported in PyTorch >= 1.0.0, though I would recommend using the latest version possible.

For example, a model without any conditional behavior is fine

```
from torch import nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(10)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(20)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(20 * 4 * 4, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.fc(x.flatten(1))
        return x
```

We can export this as follows

```
from torch import jit

net = Model()
# ... train your model

# put model in the mode you want to export (see bolded comment below)
net.eval()

# print example output
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
print(net(x))

# create TorchScript by tracing the computation graph with an example input
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
net_trace = jit.trace(net, x)
jit.save(net_trace, 'model.zip')
```

If successful then we can load our model into a new python script without using `Model`.

```
from torch import jit
net = jit.load('model.zip')

# print example output (should be same as during save)
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
print(net(x))
```

The loaded model is also trainable, however, **the loaded model will only behave in the mode it was exported in**. For example, in this case we exported our model in `eval()` mode, so using `net.train()` on the loaded module will have no effect.

---

#### Control-flow

A model like this, which has behavior that changes between passes won't be properly exported. Only the code evaluated during `jit.trace` will be exported.

```
from torch import nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(10)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(20)
        self.fca = nn.Linear(20 * 4 * 4, 2)
        self.fcb = nn.Linear(20 * 4 * 4, 2)

        self.use_a = True

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        if self.use_a:
            x = self.fca(x.flatten(1))
        else:
            x = self.fcb(x.flatten(1))
        return x
```

We can still export the model as follows

```
import torch
from torch import jit

net = Model()
# ... train your model

net.eval()

# print example input
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
net.use_a = True
print('a:', net(x))
net.use_a = False
print('b:', net(x))

# save model
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
net_trace = jit.trace(net, x)
jit.save(net_trace, "model.ts")
```

In this case the example outputs are

```
a: tensor([[-0.0959,  0.0657]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
b: tensor([[ 0.1437, -0.0033]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

However, loading

```
import torch
from torch import jit

net = jit.load("model.ts")

# will not match the output from before
x = torch.ones(1, 3, 16, 16)
net.use_a = True
print('a:', net(x))
net.use_a = False
print('b:', net(x))
```

results in

```
a: tensor([[ 0.1437, -0.0033]], grad_fn=<DifferentiableGraphBackward>)
b: tensor([[ 0.1437, -0.0033]], grad_fn=<DifferentiableGraphBackward>)
```

Notice that the logic of the branch "a" is not present since `net.use_a` was `False` when `jit.trace` was called.

---

#### Scripting

These limitations can be overcome but require some effort on your end. You can use the [scripting](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/jit.html#creating-torchscript-code) functionality to ensure that all the logic is exported.